# How can I find the state some zip code belongs to?

Tags: excel, zipcode

I have about 30,000 zip codes, and I need to extract states. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Copy [this](http://federalgovernmentzipcodes.us/free-zipcode-database-Primary.csv) csv file from [this](http://federalgovernmentzipcodes.us/) website into your workbook and then use `VLOOKUP`to lookup the state from the zip code.

Comment: Actually, I have over 30,000 entries. I tried the database that you suggested, but it does not have all the values i need, for example zip 27529. I could not find the exact match.

Comment: There's another worksheet on the website (http://federalgovernmentzipcodes.us/free-zipcode-database.csv) which contains 27529.